# How to deactive my laptop's main keyboard

Tags: keyboard

So, my laptop's keyboard doesn't work and now I'm using an external keyboard.

It works fine for a while, but way too often my laptop's main keyboard starts spamming the spacebar key. I saw some recommendations to uninstall the keyboard, but that forces a computer reset that reinstalls it. Does anyone know how can I fix this issue?

Comment: You most likely need to open the laptop and disconnect the keyboard. There normally is no option to turn it off. Consider just replacing it.

Comment: What os are you on ? Does it help : https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard ?

Comment: There is no way to disable a keyboard on a laptop. Keyboards are relatively inexpensive [~$40] for laptops, but if it's spamming the space bar, have you tried cleaning underneath the spacebar key _(either by removing the key or disassembling the laptop to remove the keyboard to clean under the key from the side)_. For cleaning electronic components in general, 90% isopropyl alcohol is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

In any laptop I am aware of, you cannot turn off the keyboard.

As you note, attempting to uninstall the keyboard software did not work and that is not surprising to me.

Two ways forward - both involve opening the laptop and getting access to the keyboard and the keyboard connector ribbon. I have done this to replace a keyboard,

(1) Disconnect the keyboard and use the external keyboard. When you have the keyboard out, it may be possible to brush out dust and see if there is debris under keys.

(2) Best alternative: Replace the keyboard. Used known good keyboards are often available on eBay so do consider this.